# Django validating empty ModelChoice form field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a form:

```
class ProjectInfoForm(forms.Form):
    module = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Module.objects.all(),
    )
    piece = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Piece.objects.all(),
        required=False,
    )
```

The second field is populated with option from the first using ajax. However, instantiating it like this is not very efficient as it means the second field is populated on page load uneccessarily (not to mention populates the field before it should).

So I tried changing it to:

```
    ...
    piece = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Piece.objects.none(),
        required=False,
    )
```

I get the desired result but of course the form does not validate has it has no choices to check against.

Is there some way I can validate the form without populating it or even better validate the two fields together as related models?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easier way is just to roll your own. You'll just need:

1. A `ChoiceField`. Using `coerce` will let you transform IDs into objects transparently
2. A view that you AJAX component can query to retrieve the list of valid `Piece`s for a given `Module`.
3. A server-side validation method that checks that the `Module` and the `Piece` correspond